# Variance of parameter estimate using recursive least squares

Tags: recursive-algorithms, time-series

I am learning about recursive least squares estimation using a forgetting factor $\lambda$ as a tool for treating time variations of model parameters and have become stuck on the following problem.

**Question**

Find an expression for $V\big[\hat{b}\big]$ given
$$y_t = bu_t + e_t, \quad t=1,...,N$$

Where $e_t$ is white Gaussian noise with variance $\sigma^2_e$ and $u_t$ is a deterministic signal such that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{t=1}^{N} u^2_t$$

is finite. The unknown parameter b is estimated as 
$$\hat{b}= \operatorname*{argmin}_b \sum_{t=1}^{N} \lambda^{N-t}(y_t-bu_t)^2,$$ where $0<\lambda \leq 1$.

**My attempt at a solution**

I can be seen that the argument that minimises the above equation is $\hat{b}= \frac{y_t}{u_t}$. However when I try to calculate the variance I get

$$V\big[\hat{b}\big]=V\big[\frac{y_t}{u_t}\big].$$ But as $u_t$ is a deterministic signal and I am under the impression that the variance of a deterministic signal is zero this would give me a zero in the denominator?

Any help greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

After user617446 comment I went back and recalculated $\hat{b}$ as follows-

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\bigg[ \sum_{t=1}^{N} \lambda^{N-t}(y_t-bu_t)^2 \bigg] = 2b\sum_{t=1}^{N}\lambda^{N-t}u_t^2-2\sum_{t=1}^{N}\lambda^{N-t}y_tu_t$$

setting this equal to zero then solving gave

$$\hat{b}=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{N}\lambda^{N-t}y_tu_t}{\sum_{t=1}^{N}\lambda^{N-t}u_t^2}.$$

I believe this to be correct but I am now stuck once again on how to calculate the variance? Grateful for any and all help.

Comment: $\hat b$ is not time dependent and hence cannot be considered to be a ratio of $y_t / u_t$. Instead, ask yourself  what  _single_ value of $b$ will minimize the expression, given $y_t, u_t$

Comment: Thanks for the hint @user617446! I have updated the question with my new calculations for the b estimate but am still stuck on calculating the variance.

Comment: Suppose you had to solve the variance of $b$ in the case $y=bu+e$  for a single $t$. Do you know what to do then?

Comment: $Var[b]=Var[\frac{1}{u}(y-e)]$ Is this what you mean? But for a single t would that not just be the variance of a constant? I.e zero? Thanks for sticking with me @user617446 !

Comment: You are almost there. For a single equation, $\hat{b}=y/u$ but $y=b u +e$ where $b$ is the "correct" value ( not the estimate). If we substitute we get  $\hat{b}=b+e/u$ and the variance is $\sigma^2/u^2$ PS: I believe that if you read up on maximum likelihood estimation, you could get more insight into these kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the least square estmation can be found via differentiation of sum by the parameter $\hat b,$ so the expression
$$\hat b =\dfrac{\sum\limits_{t=1}^N\lambda^{N-t}y_t u_t}{\sum\limits_{t=1}^N\lambda^{N-t}u_t^2}$$
is correct.

Parameter $\hat b$ should be considered as random variable whose value depends on the specific white noise sample,
$$\hat b =\dfrac{\sum\limits_{t=1^N}\lambda^{N-t}(e_t+u_t b) u_t}{\sum\limits_{t=1}^N\lambda^{N-t}u_t^2}
 =b + \dfrac{\sum\limits_{t=1}^N\lambda^{N-t}e_t u_t}{\sum\limits_{t=1}^N\lambda^{N-t}u_t^2}.$$
There are not reasons why the sums ratio can deviate the average mean of the random variable $\hat b,$ so 
$$M(\hat b) = b.$$
Then the variance is
$$V(\hat b) = M((\hat b-b)^2) = M\left(\left(\dfrac{\sum\limits_{t=1}^N\lambda^{N-t}e_t u_t}{\sum\limits_{t=1}^N\lambda^{N-t}u_t^2}\right)^2\right)\\[4pt]
 = \dfrac{M\left(\sum\limits_{t=1}^N \lambda^{2(N-t)}u_t^2e_t^2\right)
+M\left(\sum\limits_{1\leq t_1 < t_2\leq N} \lambda^{2N-t_1-t_2}u_{t_1}u_{t_2}e_{t_1} e_{t_2}\right)}{\left(\sum\limits_{t=0}^N\lambda^{N-t}u_t^2\right)^2}
 = \color{brown}{\mathbf{\dfrac{\sum\limits_{t=1}^N \lambda^{2(N-t)}u_t^2}{\left(\sum\limits_{t=1}^N\lambda^{N-t}u_t^2\right)^2}\cdot\sigma_e^2}}.$$